# npm install <module> checks all modules in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, artifactory

Doing development on a strict corporate network. We connect to an internal Artifactory for our node modules. My registry is set to our corporate Artifactory.

However, whenever I try to `npm install`, the `electron` package attempts to connect to Github which is blocked by our network. To get past this, I disconnect from my corporate network then run:

```
npm install electron@20.1.3 --registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

However, my problem is I get error messages stating:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/some-internal-module - Not found
```

In this case, `some-internal-module` (just for example) is an internal module that is of course, only uploaded in Artifactory. It is listed as one of the dependencies in my package.json.

I dont understand why doing an npm install of a single module attempts to check the dependencies in my package.json. How do I get around this? I do not want to keep removing the modules from my package.json everytime I have to install.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you publish `electron@20.1.3` to your local Artifactory? Or, even better, your corporate Artifactory? Once electron is in your Artifactory, this exercise would appear to be unnecessary.